# requestMatchers().permitAll() not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

So I want to use spring security for my project. I tested it before on a small test project and it's working as expected. But now it isn't working here.

Here is my security config. (Note that I'm using spring security 6 and spring boot 3)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http

                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())

                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/","/stuff4").permitAll()
                //.anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I'm using it with a database so I have a service which implements UserDetailsService. This is the implementation of the method

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);

        if(user.isPresent()){
            return new SecurityUser(user.get());
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email not found " + username);
    }
```

Pom seemed to long but here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>starter</name>
    <description>starter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

Here are the DEBUG logs

```
2023-03-19T23:56:36.057+02:00 DEBUG 10064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /stuff4
2023-03-19T23:56:36.075+02:00 DEBUG 10064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-19T23:56:36.108+02:00 DEBUG 10064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/stuff4?continue to session
2023-03-19T23:56:36.108+02:00 DEBUG 10064 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-03-19T23:56:36.115+02:00 DEBUG 10064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
```

And the TRACE logs

```
2023-03-20T00:01:48.122+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@a6d4547, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@701996e9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4a83d61c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@48dc06a9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@66011fbc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@435a4d2d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@253379ec, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5ff12345, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@23263586, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@33315925, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2a3c3a04, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4e2ad1f2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@495598c5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@32f243f]] (1/1)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.123+02:00 DEBUG 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /stuff4
2023-03-20T00:01:48.123+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.124+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.126+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.127+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.128+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.129+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (8/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (9/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.130+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (10/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.131+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-03-20T00:01:48.131+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (11/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.132+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (12/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.132+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.132+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.133+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@44fe1ff]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.143+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@44fe1ff] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@7bae120f
2023-03-20T00:01:48.143+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-03-20T00:01:48.143+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.143+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.144+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.145+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:188) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-03-20T00:01:48.178+02:00 DEBUG 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/stuff4?continue to session
2023-03-20T00:01:48.178+02:00 DEBUG 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-03-20T00:01:48.179+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@a6d4547, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@701996e9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4a83d61c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@48dc06a9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@66011fbc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@435a4d2d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@253379ec, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5ff12345, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@23263586, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@33315925, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2a3c3a04, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4e2ad1f2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@495598c5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@32f243f]] (1/1)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 DEBUG 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.184+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.185+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.185+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (8/14)
2023-03-20T00:01:48.188+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

This should be the important line that's making it throw the `AccessDeniedException`

```
2023-03-20T00:01:48.145+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
```

In the other test project it isn't trying to do that and it finishes on the previous line

You'd expect from what I've written here that I can access "/stuff4" and "/" but I can't. It redirects me to /login. Interesting thing is if I do .anyRequest().permitAll() it works as expected. Maybe I'm not using the requestMatchers() method correctly?

Tried playing around but it doesn't work as expected for some reason. Like I mentioned above if I do `anyRequest().permitAll()` it works as expected.

Tried making it one to one with the other config in the test project I had that works. Well this doesn't work the other one does.

Update: Added logs

Update2: Did a little bit more digging today. Found a difference in the traces with the working test project and current not working one.

The one working uses `AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer` as a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`. The one that isn't working uses `AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager` as a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`.

In the above logs it's these two lines.

```
2023-03-20T00:01:48.133+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@44fe1ff]
2023-03-20T00:01:48.143+02:00 TRACE 5932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@44fe1ff] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@7bae120f
```

Update 3: Tried solving this again today. On the working project once I access an authenticated url it uses the same `AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager`.

So the issue now becomes why does it use `AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager` when it's .permitAll(). Maybe it ignores it for some reason?

Found another difference between the working project and not working one.
The working project puts its

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.dzitestdemo.controllers.LoginController#homePage()
```

but the not working project does this

```
2023-03-24T20:31:21.606+02:00 DEBUG 4612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-24T20:31:21.607+02:00 DEBUG 4612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-24T20:31:21.607+02:00 DEBUG 4612 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
```

Got this info by logging the whole spring application + spring security.

Comment: Dont link to en external pastebin, include your code into your question. Also, why havn’t you included your full debug logs that will tell you the exact reason to why spring security is denying your request? I assume you have enabled debug logs and read them BEFORE you asked here.

Comment: Updated the question with the logs and moved the pom file here.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/1840146

Answer (score 1):

Update 4: Tested further today. I'm not really sure what happened but the only idea which might have caused the problem is this.

Before I turned on/added spring security to the project my controller was annotated with @RestController. And as you know they should be stateless. Every request has to include a way to authenticate. But after I changed it to only @Controller I suspect spring security didn't know about this change and continued to use it as a rest controller. As soon as I moved to another newly created file which was annotated with @Controller as a start and removed/commented the whole old file (the one which used to be rest controller). The SecurityFilterChain started working as expected. Then after I uncommented it later it still worked as expected. I have no way to prove that this was the issue tho.

NVM just moved it back to a @RestController and that issue doesn't persist. I have 0 idea how or why this occurred. The way I solved it(the block of text above) might not work for you.